# Import picture and scale in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I like to import a picture into Word using VBA. The picture need to be imported to a bookmark and then scaled.

I have tried with below code but have a few issues with the code. The picture is not imported to the bookmark and I haven't been able to scale the picture. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub ImportReport()

ActiveDocument.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bm1"


Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    "File_path_to_the_PNG_file", _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True
    ', _
    'ScaleWidth:=100, _
    'ScaleHeight:=100

    InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleHeight = 100
    Shapes.Item(1).ScaleWidth = 100

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end. I had 18 pictures to import. I had already created the bookmarks in the word file.

```
Sub ImportScaleWrap()

Dim ImagePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer

ImagePath = "IMAGE_PATH"
FileName = "GENERIC_PART_OF_FILE_NAME"

Dim RiskPic As InlineShape

For i = 1 To 18
    Set RiskPic = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bm" & i).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=ImagePath & FileName & i & ".png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

    RiskPic.ScaleHeight = 100
    RiskPic.ScaleWidth = 100

    Dim RiskPicType As Shape
    Set RiskPicType = RiskPic.ConvertToShape
    RiskPicType.WrapFormat.Type = wdTopBottom

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Mmm. Once you convert to a Shape the picture will no longer be "in" the bookmark. Is that OK?

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it so that it is still in the bookmark? I guess it will be easier to have it in the bookmark if like to use some code to delete it later.

Comment: Why do you turn it into a Shape? The only thing I can see in your code is WrapFormat. The same type of "wrapping" can be achieved by placing the picture in its own paragraph formatted with centered alignment. In the "template" document, put the bookmark in an "empty" paragraph and apply the center alignment. In order to delete it later: BookmarkRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete

Comment: I want the picture to cover the whole page. The picture is PNG file of a page in a PDF file. Using centre alignment I still have margins above and on the left and the picture overflows at the bottom and on the right side. Is there a way of doing it and still keep the image in a bookmark?

Comment: One possibility would be to create a TextBox (the drawing kind of text box) the size and position required. Put the bookmark IN the text box. When you insert the InlineShape at the bookmark you should be able to retain the bookmark. Note that you should set the "padding" (margins) of the text box to zero or the picture won't have the expected dimensions.